# Exception being thrown when using Transform from xml to text file via xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformer-model

My code looks as the following:

```
  protected String[] parseXMLRecievedMsg(StringBuffer iSB_plainMessage) throws Exception {

    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("sample.xslt"));
    TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transFact.newTransformer(xslt);
    StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult lS_outputMsgBody = new StreamResult( outWriter );
    iSB_plainMessage =iSB_plainMessage.delete(0,iSB_plainMessage.indexOf("\n"));
    iSB_plainMessage =iSB_plainMessage.reverse();
    iSB_plainMessage =iSB_plainMessage.delete(0, iSB_plainMessage.indexOf("\n"));
    iSB_plainMessage =iSB_plainMessage.reverse();
    StringBuilder SB_plainMessage = new StringBuilder(iSB_plainMessage.toString());
    SB_plainMessage.insert(0,"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r");

    Source lSB_MessageInput = new StreamSource(SB_plainMessage.toString());
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "text");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");




    transformer.transform(lSB_MessageInput, lS_outputMsgBody);

    return new String []{ lS_outputMsgBody.getWriter().toString()};
```

`

I'm trying to transform xml message i get to a text file.
I keep get the following exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\alltra_apps\BIC\base_domain\allNETTImport\
>   (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:79)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:440)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:234)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:524)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:709)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)

Comment: Which line of your code gives the error?

Comment: transformer.transform(lSB_MessageInput, lS_outputMsgBody);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload of the `StreamSource` constructor taking a `String` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource-java.lang.String-) expects a `String` with a URI while you seem to pass in a String with some XML constructed on the fly. If you want to read in a `String` with XML then construct a `StreamSource` over a `StringReader` over that `String`.